# How map List to an Object with list in mapstructs

Tags: java, mapstruct

How can I use `MapStruct` to create a mapper that maps a list (my source) to a object with a list (destination)?

My source classes looks like this:

```java
class SourceB {
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
}

class SourceA { 
    private Integer id;
    private List<SourceB> bs;
}
```

so I need to transform it to this:

```java
class DestinationA {
    private Integer id;
    private DestinationAB bs;
}

class DestinationAB {
    private List<DestinationB> b;
}

class DestinationB {
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
}
```

Expected sample json:

**source:**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "bs": [
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "lastname": "last1"
    },
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "lastname": "last2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**destination:**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "bs": {
    "b": [
      {
        "name": "name1",
        "lastname": "last1"
      },
      {
        "name": "name2",
        "lastname": "last2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Which library? Why don't you use same class for serialization & deserialization?

Comment: @Nand I using http://mapstruct.org/, and I need to transform a xml from my client to my world and from my json to xml

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple. Just put `@Mapping` annotation with specified `source` and `destination` on top of the mapping method.

```java
@Mapper
public interface SourceMapper {
    @Mapping(source = "bs", target = "bs.b")
    DestinationA sourceAToDestinationA(SourceA sourceA);
}
```